# How to align input boxes in a column using Zurb foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am a newbie to Zurb Foundation and I am trying to align the input elements (second div with class="large-9 columns")inline.
But they are being stacked one over the other inspite of using the class="columns".
How can i get them arranged inline?

http://jsfiddle.net/Sbt75/432/

Case 1:

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="large-3 columns">
                                Prefix:

                            </div>
                            <div class="large-9 columns">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="PrefixTab" value="Mr.">Mr.</label>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="PrefixTab" value="Mrs.">
                                    Mrs.</label>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="PrefixTab" value="Ms.">
                                    Ms.</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Case 2:

```
  <div class="row">
                        <div class="large-3 columns">
                            <label for="BirthMonthTab" ">* Birth Date:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="large-9 columns">
                            <input type="text" id="BirthMonthTab" name="BirthMonthTab" maxlength="2" />/

                        <input type="text" id="BirthDayTab" name="BirthDayTab" maxlength="2" />/

                        <input type="text" id="BirthYearTab" name="BirthYearTab" maxlength="4" />
                            (mm/dd/yyyy)

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Foundation won't help you here, you need to apply `display:inline-block;` to the input fields.

Comment: This is not Foundation specific. Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sbt75/432/

Comment: If you hit "Tidy up" on your code in that JsFiddle and then re-run it.. it will literally show everything on one line.. Sounds like you weren't closing your tags properly. Found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sbt75/434/

Comment: Are you looking for something like this for your radio buttons? http://jsfiddle.net/Sbt75/445/

Comment: @BuddhistBeast: Added an extra " in my previous fiddle. Removed that but was still not able to align them in the way I want.
Used you previous fiddle and was able to achieve it.
Updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Sbt75/446/
But since all of them were in a single column, I was under the impression that they will be aligned inline.

Comment: Those are aligned on the same line.. what browser are you using? Better yet, what do you want?

Comment: Yes they are aligning after adding display:inline-block in css.
I am using chrome.
I wanted to know if there is any way using foundation zurb to do it.
Without me adding/modifying css

Comment: @APAD1 has already declared that Foundation is useless for this. You will need to use the display method.

Comment: And I can already tell you that it is probably due to inputs putting in breaks after each tag. Which means that regardless of anything, Bootstrap, Zurb, normal HTML, you will always have that break after an input, which is why we use display:inline-block;

Comment: Yes. Got that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For case 1 you could change the radio buttons against a `<select>` field. But for both cases, you may also try something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <label class="inline right" for="BirthMonthTab">* Birth Date:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <input type="text" id="BirthMonthTab" placeholder="dd" name="BirthMonthTab" maxlength="2" />
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <input type="text" id="BirthDayTab" placeholder="mm" name="BirthDayTab" maxlength="2" />
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <input type="text" id="BirthYearTab" placeholder="yyyy" name="BirthYearTab" maxlength="4" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a demo with your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sbt75/433/ (Remember to make the preview area bigger,  or the columns will be stacked)

Comment: Yes, this is one way to do it. 
But didn't want to create too many div's just for layout.

Comment: @Vahi i can understand that, but since you have foundation in your project this will be the best way to go. Otherwise you'd have to implement some custom CSS for this your self. This is readable and easy to change for different circumstances in the project. This structure was always a help for me in the long run. But you have to decide.

Comment: Honestly, this is probably the best solution. You cannot put 3 inputs into one column and expect them to be on the same line without using a display method. @NicoO has done a great job with reminding that we can split the inputs further into more columns, which would probably make the website more responsive anyways.

Comment: thank you @BuddhistBeast you are right, that the requirement of having multiple inputs next to each other is sometimes hard to overcome. The solution you mentioned above (using inline-block) is surly one way to go. But i'am happy that i don't have to do all this work all over again thanks to such nice frameworks.